# Why don't I get an infinite loop when I call exit from an atexit handler?

Tags: c, atexit

This program register a function calling `exit()` with `atexit()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void machiavellian() {
    puts("At exit");
    exit(0);
}
int main(void) {
    atexit(machiavellian);
    exit(0);
}
```

From `man atexit`

> These callbacks must not call exit()

I was awaiting an infinite loop, but instead, it only calls once `machiavellian()`. What happens?

```
$ make you_cant_exit_me
cc     you_cant_exit_me.c   -o you_cant_exit_me
$ ./you_cant_exit_me 
At exit
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: I think the manual explains the reason perfectly.

Comment: Downvoters, care to leave a comment?

Comment: NMDV (not my down vote), but why do you expect any particular behavior if code does something improper?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I understand. The standard explicitly says that you shouldn't do that, and that for a good reason: what should the sematics of an `exit` during exit mean? Only that'd you'd allow one "module" of your application to switch off the clean up code of other modules. So what do you want to achieve or to know?

Comment: The can already switch it off, though -- they just have to call `abort()`. I think this is more a matter of allowing for programmers who don't know that their `atexit`s aren't *required* to call `exit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"These callbacks must not call exit()" does not mean "If these callbacks call exit(), special interesting things will happen". It just means "don't do it, or you're on your own". It's possible that a different POSIX-compliant system will do something else, like an infinite loop. Since you didn't follow the rules, you can't count on what will happen.

(I would assume that few if any systems would get into an infinite loop, though. It's trivial to avoid that, and I can't imagine it being a useful result.)

Comment: The *reason* you Should Not Do This is simple: `atexit` stores the function argument in a simple array, and on `exit` -- which, after all, is just a regular function and so can do *anything* -- all of these functions are called one by one. Now what *should* happen when one contains `exit` again? The observed behavior is just  "protection against stupidity", just like dividing by zero does not actually create a black hole, but only prints an error.